# Failed to su after making a chroot jail

Tags: linux, login, centos, chroot, chroot-jail

On a 64 bit CentOS host I am using script [`make_chroot_jail.sh`](http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/make_chroot_jail.sh.html) to put a user in a jail, not permitting it to see anything expect it's home at `/home/jail/home/user1`.

I did it typing this:

```
sudo ./make_chroot_jail.sh user1
```

after, when trying to connect to user1 first i was getting an error like:

```
/bin/su: user guest does not exist
```

i have fixed this by copying some missed libraries:

```
sudo cp /lib64/libnss_compat.so.2 /lib64/libnss_files.so.2 /lib64/libnss_dns.so.2 /lib64/libxcrypt.so.2 /home/jail/lib64/
sudo cp -r /lib64/security/ /home/jail/lib64/
```

But now, when trying to connect to user1 typing `su user1` and then typing it's password, i am getting this error:

```
could not open session
```

So the question is how to connect to user1 in this situation?

P.S. Here are the permissions of some files, this might be helpful in order to provide a solution:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root /home/jail/bin/su
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root /home/jail/etc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root /home/jail/etc/pam.d/su
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root /home/jail/etc/passwd
-rw------- 1 root root /home/jail/etc/shadow
```

**UPDATE1**

After some modifications i managed to connect to user1, but the session closes immediately!
I guess this a PAM issue, however cant find a way to fix it.

Here the log entry for close action from `/val/log/secure`:

```
Oct  6 15:19:42 localhost su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user user1
```

What makes the session to exit immediately after launching?

Comment: You might need to copy some system users and groups into the jail or change some configuration. On my system, `/etc/shadow` is 640 group `shadow`. Check the system logs for any relevant message and post them here. Also post the content of `/home/jail/etc/pam.d/su`. The output of `strace -s9999 su user1` could also help.

Comment: `@Gilles` After some modifications i managed to connect to user1, but now the session closes immediately. So now the question is: what makes the session to exit immediately after launching (please see the UPDATE1 of the question)? Looking to file `/val/log/secure`, i assume this is some PAM issue, however i dont know how to fix it. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `could not open session` problem, without abandoning make_chroot_jail.sh entirely, you also need to copy the `/usr/lib/libcrack*` libraries.  Edit the script, where it has:

```
# If you are using a 64 bit system and have strange problems with login comment
# the following lines in, perhaps it will work (motto: if you can't find the
# needed library just copy all of them)
#
# cp /lib/*.* ${JAILPATH}/lib/
# cp /lib/lib64/*.* ${JAILPATH}/lib/lib64/
```

Change to:

```
cp /lib/*.* ${JAILPATH}/lib/
cp /lib64/*.* ${JAILPATH}/lib64/
cp -rp /lib64/security ${JAILPATH}/lib64/
cp /usr/lib64/libcrack* ${JAILPATH}/usr/lib64/
```

Just a quick addendum, the above fixed this problem with 64 bit SuSE - SLES 11 sp2. I also renamed the `$JAILPATH/lib` to `$JAILPATH/lib64`.  And for that OS, I had to add an empty /etc/profile file in the jail (you can use it to put in a PS1 prompt).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

First of all you should forget about make_chroot_jail.sh and use [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html).

I have faced some problems while using it, but eventually everything works.

Here are the steps how I used Jailkit and how I fixed the issues which were occurring:

A. Do `./configure; make; make install` as it is describes at `INSTALL.txt`.

B. Add `/usr/sbin` to the `$PATH` if it is not already there.

C. Do this:

```
jk_init -v -j /home/jail basicshell editors extendedshell netutils ssh sftp scp
```

This may fail with an error message like this:

```
`ERROR: configfile /usr/jk_init.ini does not exist`
```

To fix this, at `/usr/sbin/jk_init` change `INIPREFIX='/usr'` to `INIPREFIX='/etc/jailkit'`  and try again.

D. Do this:

```
jk_jailuser -v -m -j /home/jail customer01
```

This may fail with an error message like this:

```
invalid shell, /home/jail/usr/sbin/jk_lsh does not exist
```

To fix do this:

```
jk_init -v -j /home/jail jk_lsh
```

and try again. You might instead add `jk_lsh` to the list at step C.

E. Now when trying to connect to customer01, the connection may exit immediately after launching. To fix this issue at `/home/jail/etc/passwd` change the shell of customer01 and set it to bash like this:

```
customer01:x:518:601::/home/customer01:/bin/bash
```

instead of this:

```
customer01:x:518:601::/home/customer01:/usr/sbin/jk_lsh
```